# How effective is compression therapy to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis

How effective is compression therapy to treat a tendinopathy?

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)

---

[Example of  compression therapy messager](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/18321388777909170404?q=arm+massager&num=50&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=890&prds=paur:ClkAsKraXxuzFKog-K7j4dq2JCls1kMlbPaq2wlEOgKDEupKZylU5Yzz4puNpQx_iB0re54yRx6puiBiO_hw32z3k2cB7nG9KH1TqdanU0KrXXmyqELtzMtYBhIZAFPVH71IC0GSICB6CU1p4YW4UwNwFaaa7A&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR9dbIwO3PAhVFPj4KHcxgALEQ8wII_AQwAw):

[image]